# How did Maxwell Derive his equations? Can we derive the same by conducting any experiment?

Tags: electromagnetism, experimental-physics, maxwell-equations, history

$$
\begin{aligned}
\nabla \cdot \mathbf{E} &=\frac{\rho}{\varepsilon_{0}} \\
\nabla \cdot \mathbf{B} &=0 \\
\nabla \times \mathbf{E} &=-\frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial t} \\
\nabla \times \mathbf{B} &=\mu_{0} \mathbf{j}+\frac{1}{c^{2}} \frac{\partial \mathbf{E}}{\partial t}
\end{aligned}
$$

Maxwell Equations are as shown in the picture

Comment: Welcome to physics.se. Your question would be better suited to [HSM](https://hsm.stackexchange.com). Apart from $\nabla\cdot\vec{B}=0$ (i.e. no magnetic monopoles exist, which to this day is empirically true), each of these laws is named for someone else. They are individually well-attested in suitable experiments. All Maxwell did is realized what happens if you put them together.

Comment: So can we derive all these equations from scratch by performing any experiment(s)?

Comment: @J.G. Well, the vector calculus part was not really Maxwell's work, but rather Heaviside's.

Comment: "So can we derive all these equations from scratch by performing any experiment(s)?" The first equation is inferred from empirical charge distributions; the third is how electric generators work; the fourth is how electric motors work, although its current term is necessitated by another general observation, namely charge conservation.

Comment: [History of Maxwell's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Maxwell%27s_equations)

Comment: @J.G. "All Maxwell did is ..." this part of your comment is not true.

Comment: @AndrewSteane Since it's otherwise useful but can't be edited, please state what else he did. I previously edited out an attempted summary NDewolf said was wrong.

Comment: @J.G. he brought in the $dE/dt$ term and figured out e.m.-waves (and maybe other stuff but I don't know)

Comment: @AndrewSteane Thanks. I realize now I should correct something I said earlier: it's that time derivative, not the current, that charge conservation necessitated.

Answer (score 10):

Maxwell was guided in the formulation of his equations by an analogy, which he worked out in mathematical detail, between the behaviour of electric and magnetic fields as then known and the behaviour of a hypothetical space-filling medium consisting of tiny spinning vortices separated by ball-bearing like idlers. The axis of spin of the vortices was analogous to the local direction of the magnetic field, so a magnetic field line was analogous to a 'string' of spinning vortices. Stress on the idlers was analogous to an electric field.

From the analogy, Maxwell was able to predict the existence of a displacement current (roughly speaking the $\frac{\partial\vec E}{\partial t}$ term in the modern presentation of Maxwell's equations). This was *not* a generalisation of previous experimental results. The especial triumph was that the vortex model predicted transverse waves, which, according to the analogy, were of electric and magnetic fields. Recent experimental measurements (equivalent to the determination of $\mu_0$ and $\epsilon_0$) enabled Maxwell to calculate the speed of the waves. It came out close to the (already known) speed of light! Maxwell famously pointed out that the conclusion seemed 'scarcely to be avoided': light was an electromagnetic wave.

Maxwell published his work on the vortex  model (or 'ether') in 1861. The paper was called *On Physical Lines of Force*. He realised that his vortex ether, hugely fruitful as it had been, was only an analogy, and in his later work he didn't refer to it, but he had garnered the equations that it yielded. In his 1865 paper, *A Dynamical Theory of the Electromagnetic Field* he presented them as equations for the cartesian components of the electromagnetic vectors, which would apply either in a vacuum or in a material medium. [The notation of vector calculus had not yet been invented.]  $\vec \nabla.\vec B=0$ doesn't, in fact, appear explicitly, but is implied by $\vec \nabla \times \vec A$ being used for what we now call $\vec B$. Yes – the vector potential started with Maxwell!

Since the vortex medium modelled the known laws of electromagnetism, it is not surprising that Maxwell's equations are *largely* generalisations, cast in differential form, of previous experimental discoveries. Looking at each equation in turn... (1) This comes from Gauss's law which,  *for stationary charges*, can be derived from Coulomb's law. Maxwell himself conducted experiments that confirmed the law to much higher accuracy than Coulomb's experiments. He correctly surmised (without experimental tests) that Gauss's law wasn't restricted to stationary charges. (2) The $\vec \nabla.\vec B=0$ law was equivalent to the well-attested observation that there are no magnetic monopoles. (3) This comes from Faraday's experimental law (for stationary circuits).

(4) For steady currents, when $\frac{\partial\vec E}{\partial t}=0$, the equation is the differential form of Ampère's line integral law, which had been amply supported by experiments with various current configurations. The $\frac{\partial\vec E}{\partial t}$ term had not been dreamt of before Maxwell. Although it emerged originally from the vortex model, Maxwell realised that without it, equation (4) would violate charge conservation except when $\vec\nabla.\vec J=0$. The propagation of electromagnetic waves in free space is now usually regarded as the best experimental support for the $\frac{\partial\vec E}{\partial t}$ term; 16 decades after it was proposed it is still not easy to provide more direct experimental evidence for it.

Comment: Fundamentally this matches my knowledge. Might be useful to note that Maxwell didn't use vector notation and his [formally equivalent] equations numbered 20 and were as concerned with fields within media as with fields in free space.

Comment: user121330 Thank you for this helpful comment. I've now expanded my third paragraph a little.

Comment: I like it! I don't see anything about the $\mathbf{H}$ or $\mathbf{D}$ (inside the magnet or charged body) fields, but I only glanced at his papers, and they may have been perfunctory mentions.

Comment: There's certainly a lot more that could be said about the 1865 equations. For example, for Maxwell a vacuum was just another medium, and two vectors (analogous to stress and strain) were needed, even for a vacuum, to describe the electric field and another two for the magnetic field. You could say that the spirit of the vortex model persisted, even if the exact mechanism had been banished.

Answer (score 1):

Maxwell didn't derive the equation in their present form (the four equations given in the OP). But yes, like most phsyics laws, these are a generalization of the experimental facts, separately known as Faraday's law, Bio-Savart law, Ampere's law, Gauss law, etc.